# Firebase Security Problem? Ninja reaction game with Vue.js + Firebase

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, backend, vuejs3

#### The problem

I am following a Vue.js 3 tutorial on youtube and I tried to implement the app shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bc6czIBLKTg).
Then I started improving it a bit at a time. You can view my project [here](https://github.com/HighLiuk/ninja-reaction-game).

One of the main features I am trying to add is a *Hall of Fame* component in which you can view the best ten scores of anyone who plays. You can submit your score just after finishing the game. I decided to use Firestore to hold the data.

However, suppose I build the app for production and host it in a server. Then, I can download the whole project on my laptop, change a little bit the logic, and then play it locally on my computer. That way, I can send any type of data to my firestore database (because my credentials are injected in the javascript by Vue). I can then just send the *ideal score* of 1 ms to hack the game (this is indeed what a friend of mine managed to do).

#### The question(s)

The question is: how can I prevent this from happening?
Should I make a few changes in the code about the firebase configuration?
Should I use some other way to store the data, and not firestore?
Should I config properly the firestore security rules?

Also, what are the best security practices in JS frameworks like Vue.js (or React, in general) to prevent the insertion of non-wanted data on the client side? How do I manage the connection to a cloud database from such front-end frameworks?

**Disclaimer**

I learn everything about programming on my own, by watching youtube videos or googling and so on. I am new not only to Vue and Firebase, but to web development in general. Please consider this when answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR;

#### If the score is calculated on client-side (in browser) you can't secure it.

Anyone can just see the API call being made from the app to the server and replicate that with rest API tool like [postman](https://www.postman.com/), so you wouldn't even need to download it locally to make changes.

If your game relies on client-side as a source of data, there is no way for the server to ensure that it is un-tampered.

You can try obfuscating the source code and doing client-side data encription, but it's all in javascript so everything is readable.

If you were to implement it in a more secure way, you would have the server trigger an action (as opposed to the script) but then the times would end up being longer because of the data turn-around time. Since the event fired from server to client and back would be reflected, but even then the automated response can be hacked by handling it with a script.

Comment: I just can't understand a word of it. Can you explain better? Also, please refer to the Disclaimer I appended to the question.

Comment: updated answer. You can make it more difficult for someone to hack it, but it's just not possible to prevent it.